# regex to retain some contents and remove everything in square brackets

Tags: python, regex

how to remove square brackets along with the strings/numbers within it but only remove the curve paranthesis and retain its contents within.

For example,

`This is a (text).[s]This is a sample[22].`

should come out as:
`This is a text. This is a sample.`

My attempt so far:

```
def _remove_regex(input_text, regex_pattern):
    pattern_lines = re.finditer(regex_pattern, input_text)
    for pattern in pattern_lines:
        input_text = re.sub(pattern.group().strip(), '', input_text)
    return input_text

regex_pattern = '\[\[(?:[^\]|]*\|)?([^\]|]*)\]\]'
_remove_regex(text, regex_pattern)
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: added my code @ScottMcC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex and `str.replace`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "This is a (text).[s]This is a sample[22]"
text = re.sub("\[.*?\]", "", s)
text = text.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
This is a text.This is a sample
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = 'This is a (text).[s]This is a sample[22].'
re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\]|[\(\)]', '', s)
# 'This is a text.This is a sample.'
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try this function:
`yourSentence = This is a (text).[s]This is a sample[22].`

```
def deleteBracketAndParenthesis (sentence):
     l = []
     for word in list(sentence):
         if ((word.split("(") is None) or (word.split("[") is None):
                l.append(word)
         elif (word.split("(") == null):
                l.append(word.split("(")[1])
     return( "".join(l) )
```

Comment: Bypassing regular expression and strange `null`s, "elsif" instead of `elif`, ...I had to downvote.